# сына мамы/ книгу друга - слова мамы и друга будут отдельными дополнениями? Если да, прямыми или косвенными?

Tags: дополнение

сына мамы/ книгу друга и т.д. - являются ли такие словосочетания цельными (синтаксически неделимыми)? Слова "мамы", "друга" в вышеприведенных словосочетаниях - прямые или косвенные дополнения? Или же вообще отдельными дополнениями не считаются, и прямыми дополнениями здесь будут целиком "сына мамы" или "книгу друга" (например, увидел кого? сына мамы, прочитал что? книгу друга)

Answer (score 0):

Это не синтаксически неделимые сочетания, а пары слов, состоящие из определяемого слова и несогласованного определения. Примеры есть в разделе про несогласованные определения в [этой статье.](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/soglasovannye-nesoglasovannye-opredeleniya.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое))